# How to have call action on Apb UserFriendlyException

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

```
 if ((input.Id > 0 && quotation.Count == 0 ) && (input.Id > 0 && proposal.Count == 0))
        {

            _contactRepository.Delete(contact);
        }
        else
        {

            throw new UserFriendlyException("Warning.", "Do you want to delete everything?.");
        }
```

Lets assume that the is a method _contactRepository.DeleteALL(contact);...
I want to execute the method DeleteALL(contact) if the user accept to delete all, but i do not know how to use the OK button on the UserFriendlyException pop up.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/mcve) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use confirmation window:

```
var r = confirm("Do you want to delete everything?");
if (r == true) {
     _contactRepository.Delete(contact);
} else {
     // do nothing
}
```

[Read more on window.confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm)